# Create toggle-able Bootstrap tabs from Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create toggle-able tabs from a Ruby hash. For example, let's say that I have the following hash:

```
tabs = {
:Friends => 
          [
            [name: 'john', age: 20, sex: 'M'],
            [name: 'elma', age: 21, sex: 'F']
          ],
:Family =>
          [
            [name: 'father', age: 50, sex: 'M'],
            [name: 'mother', age: 48, sex: 'F'],
            [name: 'sister', age: 17, sex: 'F']
          ]
}
```

This would result in the two tabs 'Friends' and 'Family' respectively which would list either friends or family members as an unordered list.

I would like to make this tabs toggle-able without Ajax if possible, so basically if I click the Friends tab it would access the appropriate value from the tabs[:Friends] hash.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to remove the answer from the question. Post the code as another answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution yesterday:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#all_tabs" data-toggle="tab">All</a>
    </li>
    <% tabs.each do |k,v| %>
        <li>
            <a href="#<%= k.to_s %>" data-toggle="tab">
                <%= k.to_s %>
            </a>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class = "tab-pane active" id = "all_tabs">
       <ul>
            <% tabs.each do |k,v| %>
                <li>
                    <%=k%>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% tabs.each do |k,v| %>
        <div class = "tab-pane" id = "<%= k.to_s %>">
            <strong><%= k.to_s %></strong>
            <ul>
                <% v.each do |key,val| %>
                    <li>
                        <%=val.name%>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the generated html output:
http://www.bootply.com/0sWdURMEPY

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it help you

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggleLink">Link to ur partial</a>
<div id="toggle_div" style="display:none">     
 <%= render partial => "ur_partial" %>
</div>
```

By using JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $('.toggleLink').click(function(){
           $('#toggle_div').toggle();
       });
   });
</script>
```

add different IDs to both tabs and toggle them...